# Filtering Search Results with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to setup a *Search Results* page with two columns. First column will present results from all categories except one ( *Galleries* ), and the second column will present only the *Galleries* category.

`query_posts()` simply resets my results. This is what I got so far. Broken:

```
        <?php 
            $s = get_query_var('s');
            query_posts('s=' . $s . '&cat=164'); 
        ?>

        <?php 
            // First Loop 
        ?>
        <div class="contentLeft">
            <ul class="postListSmall related">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    [do stuff]
                <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php 
            // Second Loop
        ?>
            <?php query_posts('cat=-164'); ?>
            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    [do stuff]
                <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>
                [do stuff]
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What to do?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/ check that out.
http://yoast.com/wordpress-search/ this one too.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind, but thanks. I need to exclude, reset and query. This is getting too specific for a plugin, and can be implemented with query_posts. I just don't understand why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I am having a similar problem and thought I would share:

1. You are creating a query, then calling a second query, but then trying to rewind the query. That's not how the rewind function works. Take a look at the [Rewind Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts). You also say:

> query_posts() simply resets my results.

Then why are you calling the rewind function immediately after the new query? Also, if you're resetting the results then why is it a different query completely? This:

```
        $s = get_query_var('s');
        query_posts('s=' . $s . '&cat=164');
```

Is not the same as this:

```
        <?php query_posts('cat=-164'); ?>
        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

To get 2 column results for different categories I did the following: use only one loop, don't use rewind, use [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) in an if statement in your loop, for example:

```
<?php 
$s = get_query_var('s');
query_posts('s=' . $s . '&cat=164'); 

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category){
        if($category->name == "category name"){
            //Concatenate to the left div
        } else {
            //concatenate to the right div
        } ?>
```

Hope this helps.